# How to augment long string containing (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,?) by replacing a '?' with the the largest neighboring number?

Tags: python, string, loops, data-augmentation

I'm trying to augment a lengthy string that can contain multiple number of digits `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,?)`
Consider a string `"000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000"`.
I'm trying to replace all the question marks `(?)` by the neighbouring largest digit. The comparison should be done from both left character and right character to the question mark `(?)`.

Input String:  `"000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000"` 
Output String: `"000000000004401110000122220110000000"`

I wrote a function that ends up replacing them during the first iteration of the loop itself which results in replacing the `?` by the highest number i.e, 4 in this case. Check the code snippet below.

Wrong Output: `"000000000004404410000144240410000000"`

```py
def method_augment(aug_str):
    global pos_of_sec_char, sec_char, preced_char
    flag_marks_string_end = 0
    list_predef = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    len_aug_str = len(aug_str)
    for m in range(0, (len_aug_str - 1)):
        if aug_str[m] == '?':
            pos_of_first_ques = m
            if m != 0:
                preced_char = aug_str[m - 1]
                # print("preced char:", preced_char)
                for n in range((pos_of_first_ques + 1), (len_aug_str - 1)): 
                    if aug_str[n] in list_predef:
                        pos_of_sec_char = n
                        sec_char = aug_str[n]
                        print(sec_char)
                        if preced_char > sec_char:
                            aug_str = aug_str.replace(aug_str[pos_of_first_ques], preced_char)
                            del preced_char, sec_char, pos_of_first_ques, m
                        else:
                            aug_str = aug_str.replace(aug_str[pos_of_first_ques], sec_char)
                            del preced_char, sec_char, pos_of_first_ques
                        break
                    else:
                        flag_marks_string_end += 1

            else:
                for q in range((pos_of_first_ques + 1), (len_aug_str - 1)):
                    if aug_str[q] in list_predef:
                        pos_of_sec_char = q
                        sec_char = aug_str[q]
                        aug_str = aug_str.replace(aug_str[pos_of_first_ques], sec_char)
                        break
            # if preced_char > sec_char:
            #     aug_str = aug_str.replace(aug_str[m], preced_char)
            # else:
            #     aug_str = aug_str.replace(aug_str[m], sec_char)

        else:
            continue

    return aug_str
```

Input String:           `"000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000"`

Expected Output String: `"000000000004401110000122220110000000"`

Actual Output String:   `"000000000004404410000144240410000000"`

There are multiple strings like this with different combinations of digit and `?`. I hope I have explained it well. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your program sounds overly complicated. I didn't even try to understand. Can you read and understand this?

```
import re


def method_augment(text: str) -> str:
    while "?" in text:
        text = replacesingle("0" + text + "0")[1:-1]   # consider starting and ending question marks
    return text


def replacesingle(text: str) -> str:
    match = re.search("\\d\\?+\\d", text)
    span = match.span(0)
    partialtext = text[span[0]:span[1]]
    left = int(partialtext[0])
    right = int(partialtext[-1])
    larger = left if left > right else right
    number_of_question_marks = len(partialtext) - 2
    text = text[:span[0] + 1] + str(larger) * number_of_question_marks + text[span[1] - 1:]
    return text


assert(method_augment("000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000") == "000000000004401110000122220110000000")
assert (method_augment("??123??1??") == "1112333111")
```

Comment: This fails on  `method_augment("??123??1")` with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'`

Comment: The requirements were not really clear, so I supposed 'any number of ??? anywhere' ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, with some tests:

```
def replace_with_largest(s):
    out = []
    last_left = None
    next_right = None
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c in '0123456789':
            out.append(c)
            last_left = c
            next_right = None # now the next digit to the right is unknown
            continue

        # Now we have a '?'.
        # We need the next digit to the right
        if next_right is None:
            for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
                if s[j] != '?':
                    next_right = s[j]
                    break
            else:
                # No more digit right of here, we'll use the last one on the left
                next_right = last_left

        out.append(max(last_left, next_right) if last_left is not None else next_right)    

    return ''.join(out)
```

The tests, some strings and the expected output:

```
tests = [("000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000", "000000000004401110000122220110000000"),
         ("??123??1", "11123331"),
         ("123???", "123333")]


for test in tests:
    print(test[0], replace_with_largest(test[0]), replace_with_largest(test[0]) == test[1])

000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000 000000000004401110000122220110000000 True
??123??1 11123331 True
123??? 123333 True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient this is but you can split your list such you retain all consecutive values of `?`s and together as separate elements, pad that list with leading and trailing characters that'll never pass as the `max` value test compared to digits or `?`s (and also make accessing indices slightly more convenient), eg:

```
import re

def augment(text):    
    w = [' ', *[el for el in re.split(r'(\?+)', text) if el], ' ']
    for i in range(1, len(w) - 1):
        w[i] = w[i].replace('?', max(w[i - 1][-1], w[i + 1][0]))
    return ''.join(w[1:-1]).strip() or None
```

Then to use it, eg:

```
cases = [
    '000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000',
    '?????????9',
    '9????????0',
    '0????????9',
    '?0???????9',
    '123???????',
    '12?????321',
    '??????????',
]

for case in cases:
    print(case, '->', augment(case))
```

Which gives you:

```
000000000004?0??100001??2?0?10000000 -> 000000000004401110000122220110000000
?????????9 -> 9999999999
9????????0 -> 9999999990
0????????9 -> 0999999999
?0???????9 -> 0099999999
123??????? -> 1233333333
12?????321 -> 1233333321
?????????? -> None
```

Comment: Thanks alot Jon.I tried it with multiple variations of the string. Works like a pro.